# Login users into Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, android-authenticator

I want to have users login to my app.

Users will be presented with following options:
Login with Google / Twitter / Facebook
Email / Register with Email

User is likely to already have Google Account configured in Settings > Android > Accounts

To get accounts on Android i see this works:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());<br>
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(null);
```

Perhaps Google Play Services can be used too for this.

*Any samples or best-practices for this?

The behavior i need is similar to Quora application.*

*More specific Questions*:
1. Should i use AccountManager or Google Play Services(how) to get Accounts on android device.
2. What should be done with non-google accounts.
3. How to go about facebook/twitter logins - will those be custom solutions
4. How do we auto-login next time user comes in

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should i use AccountManager or Google Play Services(how) to get Accounts on android device.

You should use the Google+ sign in as described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in). You can use google play services but that is more oriented to games.

> 2. What should be done with non-google accounts.

I assume you mean non-google accounts in the `AccountManager`, but you won't be using it, so this is not an issue.

> 3. How to go about facebook/twitter logins - will those be custom solutions

For facebook, you use the [Android Facebook SDK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fandroid%2F&ei=euCmVJ3TKcGfggSo54HgBg&usg=AFQjCNFmkW86zFhdW2MNBUxdtr5z6AjFMw&sig2=hrrgh68q7guPSjgP1ISEjg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY)

For twitter, you use a `WebView` for implementing the OAuth sign-in. The [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) java library can help with this. I use it.

4. How do we auto-login next time user comes in

Store the login type and authentication token in [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), a simple key-value store. Clear the preferences to log the user out.